# Stage duplication in case of dual issue pipeline

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture

I understand that in a dual-issue pipeline, the processor is capable of sustaining two executions in a single clock cycle. Talking in terms of pipeline organization (Fetch, Decode, Execute and Write), which part gets duplicated leading to the **dual** issue?

Comment: Pipelining and superscalar execution are orthogonal.

Comment: Conceptually speaking - all of them, otherwise how can each step work on a different instruction? On a finer grain inspection, you should be able to achieve some level of sharing, but it depends on the exact design.